# Multiple MySQL Instances Using systemd upgrade-safe/restart-safe?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, debian

We run MySQL 5.7.36 under Debian Buster with several instances.

For this we use the feature of Systemd described at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-systemd.html to work with ***argv[0]***. (*"@" - If the executable path is prefixed with "@", the second specified token will be passed as "argv[0]" to the executed process (instead of the actual filename), followed by the further arguments specified.* - See: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/systemd/systemd.service.5.en.html).

/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf:

```
[mysqld@replica01]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-replica01
socket=/var/lib/mysql-replica01/mysql.sock
port=3307
log-error=/var/log/mysql/replica01.log

[mysqld@replica02]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-replica02
socket=/var/lib/mysql-replica02/mysql.sock
port=3308
log-error=/var/log/mysql/replica02.log
```

Manage the instances:

```
systemctl start mysql@replica01
systemctl start mysql@replica02
```

Enable autostart:

```
systemctl enable mysql@replica01
systemctl enable mysql@replica02
```

We have deactivated the default autostart of the generic MySQL service:

```
systemctl disable mysql
```

However, when upgrading the mysql-server via package management, we have the problem that we always have to stop each instance manually first, as described in the documentation:

> On Debian platforms, the packaging scripts for MySQL uninstallation
> cannot currently handle mysqld@ instances. Before removing or
> upgrading the package, you must stop any extra instances manually
> first.

Let us now check the autostart options of the services "**systemctl list-unit-files | grep mysql**":

```
mysql.service                                     disabled
mysql@.service                                    indirect
```

If we now perform an upgrade with mysql.service disabled, no attempt is made to stop or restart the service during the package upgrade.

The idea would be to create a wrapper to override the normal mysql.service via "**sudo systemctl edit mysql**", which triggers the individual instances *mysql@replica01* and *mysql@replica02* for *start*, *stop*, *restart* and resolves the upgrade problem.

**Is this possible and does anyone have an example?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to danblack's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/302150) for putting me on the right track.
Based on the documentation and code, I have now built the following design, which seems to work:

**systemctl edit mysql**

```
[Unit]
Description=MySQL Wrapper
Wants=mysql@replica01.service
Wants=mysql@replica02.service

[Service]
Restart=no
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/bin/true
```

For each instance:
**systemctl edit mysql@replica01** *&&* **systemctl edit mysql@replica02**

```
[Unit]
PartOf=mysql.service
After=mysql.service
```

Comment: `Wants` is probably excessive. But otherwise if it works, good. Glad I could get you on the right track. Maybe on day I'll get back to make debian more considerate of template services.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble with MariaDB ([MDEV-23321](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-23321)).

[Debian Systemd packaging](https://www.mail-archive.com/pkg-systemd-maintainers@alioth-lists.debian.net/msg05264.html) isn't conducive to packaging independent template instance systemd services. But, it did give an ugly workaround in the realm of what you where considering.

I suggest in your `systemctl edit mysql.service`

```
[Unit]
PartOf=mysql@replica01
PartOf=mysql@replica01

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl disable mysql.service
```

`ExecStart=` (blank) is needed tor reset the list.

This should be just enough to trigger the restart and keep the mysql.service from starting a new instance, no fail, and not look misleading in the list-instances.

ref: [dh_installsystemd code](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/debhelper/-/blob/main/dh_installsystemd#L392)